# The target type of this expression must be a functional interface: Function vs Consumer

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, lambda

In **Code 1:** there are no errors and it works.
The **Code 2** has the mentioned compile time error.

**Question 1**:
Why?

**Question 2:**
How do we return a Function in Code 2?

Code 1:

```
static <T> Consumer<T> m1(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    Consumer<T> c = obj -> {
        consumer.accept(obj);

    };
    return c;
}
```

Code 2:

```
static <T, R> Function<T, R> m2(Function<T, R> f) {
    // Compile Error: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
    Function<T, R> o = {x -> {
        f.apply(x);
    }};
    return o;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code 2, I get your error in Eclipse, which is not helpful.  When compiling on the command line, I get this error:

```
J.java:28: error: illegal initializer for Function<T,R>
                Function<T, R> o = {x -> {
                                   ^
  where T,R are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in method <T,R>m2(Function<T,R>)
    R extends Object declared in method <T,R>m2(Function<T,R>)
J.java:28: error: lambda expression not expected here
                Function<T, R> o = {x -> {
                                    ^
2 errors
```

Your braces are unnecessary.  The outer pair of braces is attempting to create an array initializer, not a lambda expression.  The inner braces does attempt to create a lambda expression, but that can't be done within an array initializer.

You can have an expression be the return type of a lambda expression, without any braces.  Try:

```
Function<T, R> o = x -> f.apply(x);
```